# VS studio does not show value of new variable during debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Have a class

```
public class ABC
{
  private wt;
  private nos;
  MyDictionary1;
  MyDictionary2;

  public void XYZ(some arguements)
  {
    // Dictionaries are populated here ( I can see the contents during debug)

    wt = MyDictionary1[arguements.key]; // wt was added last week. shows value during debugging
    no = MyDictionary1[arguements.key]; // Added no today, does not show value during debudding
   }

}
```

The control does do to the line where no is being assigned a value. But when I add it to watch, VS says 'no' does not exist in current context. If both the variables are declared and populated the same way, I do not know why this is happening. 
Can someone please help?

Comment: is that typo "no" == "nos"?

Comment: Yes, its "nos" at both places. Sorry

Comment: did your problem fixed now? how could you debug when you get error at compiletime

Comment: Please post code that is actually valid. It's really hard to tell where a problem might be if the code isn't valid to start with.

Comment: Place the breakpoint *after* the line to be executed, not on it. Since its the last line in the method, place the breakpoint on the closing brace of the method. Either that or step to the next statement after hitting the breakpoint.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Or you can place it on the line, then press F10 to step over and *then* check the value in `no` (or `nos` or whatever it's supposed to be).

Comment: Can not post any more code, sorry about that :(
I have seen VS do this earlier as well. I am using VS Ultimate 13. The breakpoint is after the nos = MyDictionary... line... I am trying to run step by step.. It just does not recognize the variable not gives me any errors.

Comment: This can also happen if you are running the debugger in release mode and it has optimized away `nos`.

Comment: `private nos`. What's that mean? Where is the type? Paste the code as is.

Comment: @SaurabhSahasrabuddhe: If you can't give enough information for people to be able to reproduce the problem, then how do you expect anybody to be able to help? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Matt, i will keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clean Solution and after that Build Solution. If it doesn't work, delete the bin and obj folders, build solution and try again.